# Is there a C++ hash function that returns hash as a mixture of letters and strings?

Tags: c++, string, hash, stl, hash-function

I know that the STL std::hash class in C++ returns hash only in form of numbers even for strings. But I want to have a hash function which returns the hash as a mixture of letters and alphabets on passing an integer in c++ with less collisions. Is there any standard library function that I can use?

I want something like this:
H(12345) = a44f81ji234kop
with least number of collisions and a good distribution.

Comment: No, there's no such hash function in the standard library, The [`hash` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Hash) requires to get a `std::size_t` value.

Comment: Hashes produce bits; it's up to you how you interpret those bits.

Comment: Can you clarify what "a mixture of letters and strings" is?  Strings can contain numbers and letters.

Comment: This post has an almost overwhelming aroma of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), so why don't you tell us what you're *really* trying to do? Why *exactly* do you need this? This sounds like you want a base64-encoded cryptographic digest. It would no-doubt give you a decent distribution, not that you could use it for anything (certainly not for a key to a std::unordered_map, which is just going to turn it into a number anyway). And when you say, *"... with less collisions"* - less collisions than *what* ? `std::hash<int>` ?

Comment: Your output format looks like a base32, base36 or base64 encoding of raw bytes. There's nothing special about that; you could easily convert a numeric result to that format. I agree with @WhozCraig this sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can pick any normal hash function you like, then do the conversion to "a44f81ji234kop"-style text as a second step (discussed below).  The Standard Library doesn't attempt to provide any guarantees on hash function quality, so as you seem to want those, you're better off picking a third party library, e.g. https://github.com/stbrumme/hash-library

Once you have a number, you can use [base-36 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) to convert it to the kind of numbers-plus-text representation you prefer.  You can specify base when converting

- int->text using [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars),
- text->int (i.e. if you want to get the numeric hash value back from the base 36 value) using [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard library lacks functionality to combine hashes or hash multiple object of different type into one hash, unfortunately.

One good way is to use the hashing infrastructure from [Types Don't Know #](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html):

> The problem solved herein is how to support the hashing of N different types of keys using M different hashing algorithms, using an amount of source code that is proportional to N+M, as opposed to the current system based on `std::hash<T>` which requires an amount of source code proportional to N*M. And consequently in practice today M==1, and the single hashing algorithm is supplied only by the `std::lib` implementor. As it is too difficult and error prone for the client to supply alternative algorithms for all of the built-in scalar types (`int`, `long`, `double`, etc.). Indeed, it has even been too difficult for the committee to supply hashing support for all of the types our clients might reasonably want to use as keys: `pair`, `tuple`, `vector`, `complex`, `duration`, `forward_list` etc.